# Multiple NSArray's and common objects

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

So I have multiple NSArrays(5 actually), and I would like to create a new NSArray containing only objects common to ALL arrays. Is there an efficient way to do this. The only way I can think of, is to loop through all the arrays comparing each object.

Comment: I think you must loop through them…

Comment: You mentioned finding a simpler solution in the comments on the previous question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ChrisHaze ah sorry, I edited my original question with my solution. Ill add it as a new answer and accept it as correct. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using this which works quite well:

```
NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array];
NSMutableSet *set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array2];
NSMutableSet *set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array3];
NSMutableSet *set3 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array4];
NSMutableSet *set4 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array5];

[set intersectSet:set1];
[set intersectSet:set2];
[set intersectSet:set3];
[set intersectSet:set4];

NSArray *allArray = [set allObjects];
```

Comment: My goal was to tally the totals of matching instances and poised a similar scenario, but not exactly. Thanks for posting it: I've decided to go the NSCountedSet approach, after dumping all the NSArrays' contents into it and it seems to be working. I'm not sure about scalability though. Thanks again @gypsyDev

Answer (score 3):

<s>Why not create an NSSet (NSMutableSet, really), dump the contents of all 5 arrays into it, and then construct a new NSArray from the NSSet?</s>

Sorry, I misread your question originally.  Yes, I think you pretty much have to loop through each one to find the duplicates.  But it's not so terrible to implement (might be somewhat slow at runtime if your arrays are huge, however).

Here's some example code:

```
- (void) filterSet: (NSMutableSet*)set withArray: (NSArray*) array {
    NSMutableSet* removals = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:[array count]];
    for (id obj in set) {
        if (! [array containsObject: obj]) {
            [removals addObject: obj];
        }
    }
    [set minusSet: removals];
}

NSMutableSet* mySet = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:[array1 count] * 5];
[mySet addObjectsFromArray: array1];
[self filterSet: mySet withArray: array2];
[self filterSet: mySet withArray: array3];
[self filterSet: mySet withArray: array4];
[self filterSet: mySet withArray: array5];

NSArray* filteredArray = [mySet allObjects];
```

Comment: that will create an array containing all objects though, I just want the duplicates. I think NSSet is what i'm looking for though, I found this method: intersectSet:

Comment: @gypsyDev - Ah, sorry, you want all the duplicates.  This is doing the opposite.  I misread and thought you wanted all the uniques.

Comment: @gypsyDev - Okay, I patched it up to find/keep the duplicates.

Comment: i found an even simpler solution added to my question: